# Display PDF using Spring REST and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, pdf

I spent a couple of days on this problem and read hundreds posts. But i still can't resolve it.

**REST Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/goodInStocks/loadlist={id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> loadList(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    byte[] bytes = pdfService.loadList(id);
    String filename = "report.pdf";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", filename);
    if (bytes.length == 0) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Angular Service:**

```
function getLoadList(id){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI+'loadlist='+id, {responseType : 'arraybuffer'})
        .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching load list');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
function loadList(documentId){
        GoodInStockService.getLoadList(documentId)
            .then(
                function(d){
                    var file = new Blob([d.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var fileURL = url.createObjectURL(file);
                    window.open(fileURL);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while getting Load list');
                }
            )

    }
```

Finally, I get new tab in browser with next error "Failed to load PDF document"
I tried to use different headers in rest controllers, create Blob from response, add 'produces="application/pdf' property in rest controller's method(by the way, in this way i got 406 error - why?)Also, i detect that arraybuffer(if i don't set length in header) and byte[] have different length, is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write directly to response and flush/close.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/goodInStocks/loadlist={id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void loadList(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, HttpServletResponse response) {
  byte[] byteArray= pdfService.loadList(id);
  response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
  OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
  os.write(byteArray);
  os.flush();
  os.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!Can u explain why my variant doesn't? I understand that I get wrong ArrayBuffer. But why?

Comment: I guess it tries to serialize the bytes in your case instead of writing them directly to stream. So browser in your case does not thing it's file but some  JSON with bytes.